# Finding End user response time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, response-time

How can we capture the end user response time in **JMeter**?
If there is any **plug-ins** available?
Can u please help me.

Comment: You can leverage Selenium WebDriver sampler in JMeter to measure the client-side performance.

Answer (score 1):

As per the main page of the [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) project

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time)

Well-behaved JMeter test acts quite similarly to read users using real browsers given you properly handle embedded resources, [cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), AJAX calls, etc. See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for JMeter tuning recommendations.

I would also recommend using i.e. [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) or [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) to measure real life user experience while the main load is being conducted using JMeter, this way you will be able to get more precise picture.